# How can we get prepare the proof for crowdloan pallet?

Tags: crowdloan, moonbeam

I am working on the moonbeams crowdloan pallet. In associate_native_identity extrinsic we need proof: MultiSignature in parameter.

how can we get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use polkadot js signing for that [sample link](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8844#/signing)

In that for data you can read below

The format of data is: b"" "SignatureNetworkIdentifier" + "new_account" + b""
https://github.com/PureStake/crowdloan-rewards/blob/main/src/lib.rs#L220

We need to convert that fields into hex and join and the out put will be the data which we can sign and and that signature proof we can use it as proof.
to convert the data into hex you can use this web: https://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter

```
<Bytes>: 3c42797465733e
sign- (SignatureNetworkIdentifier): 7369676e2d
account hex: 88fd77d706e168d78713a6a927c1ddfae367b081fb2829b119bbcc6db9af401d
</Bytes>: 3c2f42797465733e
```

data after merge it: 0x3c42797465733e7369676e2d88fd77d706e168d78713a6a927c1ddfae367b081fb2829b119bbcc6db9af401d3c2f42797465733e

you can use it is data
then sign the data and you will get the proof which you can use it in extrinsics.